# How to solve Renderer Conflict? (Xamarin.forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm making app using with Xamarin.forms.

I had my own renderer linked with ContentPage. 
And I added a solution someone made on my solution because I need his function.
Problem is that it has a renderer linked with ContentPage too.

So Only One renderer works now. (only one OnAppears fired)

Of course I could do hand merge those two function. 
Is that how it's done?

Any better solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have both behaviours then you will probably need to merge them. There's no way of telling which one it will use when the same type is referenced by both. However it always picks the most specific element type. That's why when you need more control you're probably better off subclassing `ContentPage` and attaching your own renderer to the subclass instead. Your content pages would then inherit from the subclass instead of the default `ContentPage`. That way other renderers can't get in the way either.